# Why doesn't android Webview check for cache by default?

Tags: android, caching, android-webview

I have a webview using application caching. I launched the app with a connection to the network in order to load/cache the page. Now, after turning the wifi (and 3g - no network connection) off, and launch the app, I get shown the "android could not load the page" page. Oddly, if I then reload the webview, it loads up the page from cache. Why doesn't it load this page from the cache if it can't connect to the network?

I'm using HTML5 Application Cache with cache.manifest. Here's my webview code to enable this:

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.my.package/cache");
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

I tried adding in:

```
weview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: When you turn off the wifi and/or 3g, are you now killing the instance of the application, unless you are actively checking, it wont know to load from cache because it already loaded from network, this is why when you reload the webview it loads correctly.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I don't understand what you mean, but the flow is this: 1. Load app from network. 1a. Page is cached. 2. Kill app. 3. Kill wifi (no 3g on device) 4. Load app. 4a. Page shows "Android could not load the page" 5. Refresh the webview. 5a. Page loads correctly from cache

Comment: How are you refreshing the webview?

Comment: Just with a button that calls `loadUrl` again. It's literally the same call that is made in `onCreate`.

Comment: Either you can always check for network connections and then reload or simply reload in onResume after the instance is killed?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the URL you're requesting isn't a redirect. If it is, the cache will be pointing to that redirect as well, and the WebView won't read the resulting redirect from the cache.

It took me some time to figure out that this was what was happening in my case.